# Problems importing a .lib into another project

Tags: c++, import, wxwidgets

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 under Windows 7. I have a .lib and accompanying .h files (which make use of wxWidgets  if that makes a difference) which compile without any issues.

I'm trying to import that library into a GUI project but when I do, the main class I'm interested in doesn't appear to be there?

I've added `#include "MyLib.h"` to the gui and added `mylib.lib` to the including libraries but for some reason I get:

```
MyLib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MyLibClass::MyLibClass(void)" (??0MyLibClass@@QAE@XZ)
```

Why might that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe are you referencing an old version of the library? Are you sure the linked libraries in the project settings are set to the right path?

Comment: Got it - I'd changed the output directory a while ago and was using the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do a rebuild of MyLib.lib and then add it to the second project by adding:

#pragma comment (lib,"C:\full\path\to\lib\here.lib")

to any source file.

If it works, then you know you have a problem with your paths

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you built the library, you didn't include all the object files. Note, in particular, that it's `mylib.obj` that's showing the unresolved external. It seems fair to guess that `mylib.obj` is in `mylib.lib`, in which case it's saying that mylib.lib doesn't include all the "stuff" it depends upon.